# CircleCI 2.0 iOS build stuck at Signing

Tags: ios, react-native, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I am building my React Native iOS app with circleci 2.0, my build is stuck at Signing for about 40 minutes and not moving ahead.
I have my apple id with 2FA so have added FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD in environment variables.
My github id is also having 2FA and have deployed adhoc certificates on git with GH_TOKEN in circle ci env. variables.

My Fastlane file looks like this -

```
update_fastlane

default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  before_all do
    setup_circle_ci
  end
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "xxxApp.xcodeproj")
    match(type:'adhoc')
    gym(export_method: "ad-hoc")
    build_app(workspace: "xxxApp.xcworkspace", scheme: "xxxApp")
    # upload_to_testflight
  end
end
```

My circle ci config.yml looks like this

```
version: 2
jobs:
  node:
    working_directory: ~/sekuraRN
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.16.0
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: set Ruby version
          command: echo "ruby-2.4" > ~/.ruby-version
      - run: npm install
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ~/xxxApp
          paths:
            - node_modules
  ios:
    macos:
      xcode: '11.2.1'
    resource_class: large
    working_directory: ~/xxxApp
    shell: /bin/bash --login -o pipefail
    steps:
      - checkout
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "XXXXXXXX"
      - run:
          name: set Ruby version
          command: echo 'chruby ruby-2.5.7' >> ~/.bash_profile

      - run:
          name: Update Bundler version
          command: sudo gem install bundler:2.1.1

      - restore_cache:
          key: npm-v1-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}-{{ arch }}

      - restore_cache:
          key: node-v1-{{ checksum "package.json" }}-{{ arch }}

      - run: npm install
      - save_cache:
          key: npm-v1-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}-{{ arch }}
          paths:
            - ~/.cache/npm
      - save_cache:
          key: bundle-v1-{{ checksum "ios/Podfile.lock" }}
          paths:
            - ./Pods
      - save_cache:
          key: node-v1-{{ checksum "package.json" }}-{{ arch }}
          paths:
            - node_modules
      - run:
          command: bundle install
          working_directory: ios
      - save_cache:
          key: bundle-v1-{{ checksum "ios/Gemfile.lock" }}-{{ arch }}
          paths:
            - vendor/bundle
      - run:
          name: Setup MFSDK Configuration
          command: echo -e "machine repo.active.ai\nlogin docs@active.ai\npassword docs@123" > ~/.netrc
      - run:
          name: Uninstall Cocoapods
          command: gem uninstall cocoapods
      - run:
          name: Install Cocoapods
          command: gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
      - run:
          name: Pod Install
          command: pod install
          working_directory: ios
      - run:
          name: update fastlane
          command: bundle update fastlane
          working_directory: ios
      - run:
          name: Building IPA
          no_output_timeout: 30m
          command: bundle exec fastlane beta 
          working_directory: ios

      - store_artifacts:
          path: ios/xxx_app
          destination: ipa/

workflows:
  version: 2
  node-android-ios:
    jobs:
      - node
      - ios:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
          requires:
            - node
```

Output from CircleCI -

```
[07:47:40]: ▸ the transform cache was reset.
[07:49:45]: ▸ Touching xxxApp.app
[07:49:45]: ▸ Signing /Users/distiller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/…
```

It doesn't move ahead and stuck at this for 40 mins

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? i am facing the same behavior in my circleCI build